# If Veda vakyams are "eternal" because they are repeated every kalpa, then why can't other vakyams also be eternal because they are repeated?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, apaurusheyatva

Some people say that the veda-vakyams are eternal because they are repeated every kalpa. So vakyams like "yathA purvam akalpayat" (he created the universe just as before) are eternal. But so what? Even laukika (ordinary) statements like "Today is a hot day", "my wife is beautiful", etc. are repeated by millions of people every kalpa, and hence they are eternal.

Even statements contradicting the Vedas like "there is no God" are repeated every kalpa by millions of atheists. So if the Vedas are "eternal" in this sense, then their eternality has no significance because they would be just like nitya-laukika (eternally ordinary) statements.

Comment: Yes They are also  eternal but they shara temproary like jiva, Jiva is eternal but temprorary like they undergo birth and death..similarly all shadbas are eternal even bad words but temprorary they undergo changes like birth and death but not vedas are same and eternal this was stated by Sriman Madvacharya, Serva shabhda speaks only about God.

Comment: Vedas are cosmic sounds ever present.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti "Vedas are cosmic sounds ever present." - that makes ZERO sense, especially when they record historical occurrences, sexual affairs, etc. It's just a text composed like any other text: based on facts.

Comment: Ikshvaku you have to know then what's vedas. Rishis heard the vedic sounds in deep meditation

Comment: by definition, the visible universe is Laukika (from the word Loka). Why place Srushti (creation is the first most laukika event ever because that's what creates Lokas) on a different pedestal than any other aspect inside creation ?